# Filling column in List Contol with setItemText

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to fill my column in List control (m_listCtrl) in MFC. I want to do it in that way :

```
void CMy1domacanalogaRadixDlg::sort()
{
     // some code here

    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        a[i] = b[i];
        niz.Format(_T("%d"), a[i]);
        // here choose column and add numbers
        m_listCtrl.SetItemText(i,counter,niz); 
    }   
}
```

I want to create columns dynamically, because I want to add every for loop iteration in own column, but the problem is that I need to press button "Sort" on my form twice to display numbers in column. It's all work fine, I have all numbers in column but not on first button press. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is `b`, and is it valid and populated on the first call to `sort()`?

Comment: It's a radix sort implementation. `b` is a bucket and is vaild and populated on the first call to `sort()`.

Comment: I tried to add `Invalidate()` in button click method but doesn't help.

Comment: Solved. I used `setItemText()` method before `InsertColumn()` method. I'm idiot. Thanks for your time and sorry.